# Spring Boot(1.3.5) Static resources not being served

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I've a spring boot application with some static content under

```
\src\main\static -> test.html
```

On building with Maven, this is getting into

```
target\classes\static -> test.html
```

Main file looks like below

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

Applications context path in application.properties is set to

```
server.contextPath=/myapp/api/
```

test.html is not available under any of the below path

```
localhost:8080/test.html
localhost:8980/myapp/api/test.html
```

Can you please let me know what I'm missing ?

Comment: Adding comment on what is missing will help me correct the question. Just a down vote wont :(

Comment: Do you really mean `src/main/static`? It should be `src/main/resources/static`. Also, how are you running the application once you've built it?

Comment: I've tried both of those path @AndyWilkinson. No luck. Based on this documentation https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot looks like /static is also supported though.

Comment: @Anand The supported filepaths are relative to src/main/resources, e.g. src/main/resources/resources, src/main/resources/static, src/main/resources/public

Comment: @punkrocker27ka Even the test.html inside the src/main/resources not accessible. Getting 404.

Comment: @Anand Again, you need an additional subfolder named either public, static, resources, etc.  See my previous comment.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka ya.. I've tried that as well..all of your combinations..  Still no luck :(

Comment: @Anand Please share a full sample project on GitHub so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code was in one of the controller file taking routing precedence for static content as well. Removing this solves the issue.

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public void unmappedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    throw new UnknownResourceException("There is no resource for path " + uri);
}
```